# Test error handling of the PHP S3Client uploadAsync method

Tags: php, unit-testing, amazon-s3, phpunit

Method `uploadAsync` automatically decides and uploads object in single or multiple chunks. And we can expect 2 different kind of expectations `S3Exception` and `S3MultipartUploadException` in our `$result['reason']`. I'm trying to mock part of the S3 client to throw the exception, I have done this by MockHandler:

```
$s3->getHandlerList()->setHandler(new MockHandler([$result], null, null));
```

And the `$result` is:

```
new S3Exception("", new Command("mockCommand"), [
                    'code' => 'mockCode',
                    'response' => new Response(401)
                ])
```

Or either this:

```
new S3MultipartUploadException(new UploadState(['testid']))
```

Since the `S3MultipartUploadException` is not instance of `AwsException` I got this exception:
`InvalidArgumentException: Expected an Aws\ResultInterface or Aws\Exception\AwsException.`

How can I handle such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked this on the project repo and they confirmed this is a bug https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/2143.